# How can I copy the dynamic layout behavior from one control to another?

Tags: dynamic, layout, mfc, dialog

How can one programmatically copy the dynamic layout behavior of one dialog control to another one on runtime?

I have set the properties to one control via the IDE resource editor and would like to use this as a "template" for other controls programmatically created on runtime.

[image]

I know that I can test whether or not an element is already handled by the CMFCDynamicLayout using [CMFCDynamicLayout::HasItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cmfcdynamiclayout-class?view=msvc-170#hasitem) but how can I retrieve its behavior settings, i.e. its [Move Settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cmfcdynamiclayout-class?view=msvc-170#movesettings_structure) and its [Size Settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cmfcdynamiclayout-class?view=msvc-170#sizesettings_structure) ?

Comment: What's the specific use case? Copying the dynamic layout behavior from one control to another doesn't immediately sound like a reasonable approach. After all, the layout is specific to the controls involved.

Comment: The settings in the property editor are stored as "styles" or "extended styles" in the resource script (`WS_...` or  `WS_EX_...`). So if you are not sure which style each property corresponds to, all you have to do is place two controls on a dialog (differing only in the properties you are interested in), open the resource script (.rc) as text/code (it will close the resource editor) and compare the control styles in the script.

Comment: @con [Dynamic layout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/dynamic-layout) is an MFC-specific extension. It has nothing to do with (extended) window styles.

Comment: Then the most reasonable approach would be call the `CWnd::GetDynamicLayout()` function and then call `CMFCDynamicLayout::AddItem()` for the programmatically created controls (with the desired Move and Size settings).

Comment: @con It's finding the *"desired Move and Size settings"* that this question is asking about. Though I'm having a feeling the OP assumes MFC's dynamic layout were more versatile than it actually is.

Comment: @IInspectable The usecase is the programatic generation of n buttons at position determined by the template. All those buttons should move the same way as the template button. A similar use-case is the placement of a custom control in the window-rect of a placeholder-control (placed with the IDE tool). Transferring the "property" of this template placeholder. There are always workarounds for the dialog, but I was hoping that such a thing as "getting" a property (also for checking) would be somehow supported...

Comment: It's not easy to do because the interface only offers the `AddItem()` function. Everything else is hidden in the implementation. Checked the sources (afxlayout.cpp and .h) and the class stores these in the private member `m_listWnd`, however there is a protected member `FindItem()` which returns this info. Maybe you can implement a descendant class. Even the `AFX_DYNAMIC_LAYOUT_ITEM` struct is defined in the implementation source! You will have to redefine it in your source and cast the result returned, hoping it will work...

Comment: @ConstantineGeorgiou Thanks for looking into this. I think, the answer to my question then rather is: "Sorry, no MFC doesn't provide this". Not ideal, but better than me hunting the internet for some nonexistent code ;c)

Comment: Maybe the "solution" I described above would work, but I still don't get how this would be useful: you will still have to change the resource script to define the "template placeholder", while the alternative would be to define it (once) in the code (which is almost the same amount of work), but without having to programmatically retrieve and copy it. I think it's not worth the effort then, am I wrong?

Comment: If all else fails you could read the raw binary resource that stores the dynamic layout information, and parse out the individual entries. I believe the format isn't documented, but it isn't exactly complex either. The `CMFCDynamicLayout` implementation provides all the information you'd need.

Comment: @IInspectable Thanks, but I think that is just not worth it. The intent of my question was to verify that it is not easily doable (or find out how it would be).